# Creating a Bookshelf view in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image

I have seen many e-book readers with the Bookshelf design where books are placed like iBooks for Apple or iReader for Android. I am trying to build a similar bookshelf UI in Android. I have prepared the graphics for the layout namely shelf_left (34*180), shelf_right (34*180) and shelf_center (652*180). Currently I am targetting 720*1280 pixel density devices, so I have kept the total width as 720px. I am using dp as my length unit.

I am using RelativeLayout as my root layout. When I am putting all my images in the layout, the images are not getting aligned properly. The shelf_center gets extra top and bottom padding and the side images looks too big.

I am not able to figure out how to control this behavior. Below is the code for my main.xml layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shelf_left"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button"
        android:src="@drawable/shelf_left" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shelf_center"
        android:layout_width="652dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/shelf_right"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shelf_left"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button"
        android:src="@drawable/shelf_center" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shelf_right"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button"
        android:src="@drawable/shelf_right" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how it looks:

http://img210.imageshack.us/img210/2885/shelf.png

Please help me figure out what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: This is good [**reference**](http://code.google.com/p/shelves/) for start.

Comment: hi Yul, Thanks for your reply and help. I still couldn't get time to apply these solutions. I will get back to you when i'll try this. Thanking You, Rajan – Rajan

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the center image is too wide to fit the view and is scaled down. Note that the vertical wooden sides in the side views don't match to the image of the bottom view. Have you tried using `android:scaleType` so that the images don't get scaled?

Also, double check that the measurements in pixels (you mention the images' sizes in pixels) match the values in `dp` set in the XML.

Comment: hi frozenkoi, Thanks for your reply and help. I still couldn't get time to apply these solutions. I will get back to you when i'll try this. Thanking You, Rajan